# React Js Date Range Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-day-picker library to for date rage picker [react-day-picker library url](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/months-multiple) but I want to show this calendar on my button click event. How to achive this.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used simple code "<DayPicker numberOfMonths={2} />;" and it rendring on my page by default but i want render this on my button click event

Answer (score 2):

how about setting a flag before rendering the component by using the state?

ex.

a button click can call renderCalendar method

```
renderCalendar(){
  this.setState({showCalendar:true})
}
```

and instead of doing :

```
<DayPicker numberOfMonths={2} />
```

wrap it inside a conditional statement

```
{ this.state.showCalendar ? 
       //show the calendar
       <DayPicker numberOfMonths={2} /> : 
        //Do not show the calendar
        null
}
```

Comment: Hi @xSkrappy thanks, I've already tried this one it's wokring also but i am looking for other option like if there is any property available to hide nd show the calendar like DayPickerInput component then that will more proper way. If any other way then plz provide me solutinos

Comment: I guess you need to search for it in the documentation :)

Comment: [Here](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker) are all the APIs that component provides but sadly none of them match your requirements. You would have to go with your current work.

Comment: select start date and end date